# How to auto refresh QSqlTableModel whene added a new data to a database PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5

I want the tableview automatically refresh when there is a new data added to the database

this is my py file

```
from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5 import QtSql, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
import sys, sqlite3
import psycopg2
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate

import sys


from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType


ui, _ = loadUiType('test.ui')


class MainApp(QMainWindow, ui):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.Handel_Buttons()

    
    def Handel_Buttons(self):
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.Handel_Day_Operations_1)

    def Handel_Day_Operations_1(self):

        connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                               password="password",
                               host="localhost",
                               database="database")
        self.cur = connection.cursor()

        patient_name = self.lineEdit.text()
        medecin_name =self.comboBox.currentText()
        date_f = datetime.date.today()
        time_f = datetime.datetime.now().time()

        self.cur.execute(''' INSERT INTO transactions(patient, medecin, date_d, time_d, montant, C_acte, acte, users_id ) 
            VALUES (%s ,%s, %s, %s,)
        ''', (patient_name , medecin_name, date_f, time_f,))

        connection.commit()

        
        
        self.lineEdit.setText('')
        
        self.Show_tran_table()
        

    def Show_tran_table(self):
        database = QSqlDatabase("QPSQL")
        database.setHostName("localhost")
        database.setDatabaseName("database")
        database.setUserName("postgres")
        database.setPassword("password")
        database.open()
        
        model_ft = QSqlTableModel(db=database)
        model_ft.setTable('transactions')
        
        model_ft.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal,"id")
        model_ft.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal,"medecin")
        model_ft.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal,"patient")
        model_ft.setHeaderData(3, Qt.Horizontal,"date")
        model_ft.setHeaderData(4, Qt.Horizontal,"temps")
        
        # model_ft.removeColumns(8,1)
        date = str(datetime.date.today())
        date_1 = str(datetime.date.today() - timedelta(days = 1))
        
        self.tableView.setModel(model_ft)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        
        model_ft.setSort(0, Qt.DescendingOrder)
        
        model_ft.select()
        filter_ft = "(date_d, time_d) > ('%s'::date, '16:00:00'::time) AND (date_d, time_d) < ('%s'::date, '16:00:00'::time) " % (date_1, date)
        model_ft.setFilter(filter_ft)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    #app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('sifax.ico'))
    window =  MainApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and this is the ui file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1222</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QTableView" name="tableView">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>30</x>
      <y>160</y>
      <width>1171</width>
      <height>331</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Merienda One</family>
      <pointsize>11</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>220</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>341</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Merienda One</family>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="placeholderText">
     <string>Nom du Patient</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_32">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>161</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Merienda One</family>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Nom Complet de patient</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>570</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>351</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Merienda One</family>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="placeholderText">
     <string>Nom du Médecin</string>
    </property>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>0</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>1</string>
     </property>
    </item>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>980</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>81</width>
      <height>51</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Ajouter</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I try a simple solution that it refresh the table every specific time using this

```
timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.Show_tran_table)
        timer.start(5000)
```

but I get into another problem when I want to update a value in the table I have to be faster than 5 s or the table will refresh and I can't update any value

this gui work on 2 part the first one is for adding data and the 2nd part is for showing data only (the same thing here, but only the table view), what I want when someone add data to the database using the def Handel_Day_Operations_1 (self):in the 2 nd gui that contain only the table view it will refresh automatically with the new row that has been added

Comment: "new data added to the database" by what? Besides that: 1. It's "handle", not "handel"; 2. Only classes and constants should have capitalized names, functions and variables/attributes should always begin with a lowercase letter.

Comment: thank you for correcting my code I will fix it and I'm sorry English is not my native language

Comment: no problem. You still haven't answered my question, though.

Comment: Ooh, so sorry, this gui work on 2 part the first one is for adding data and the 2nd part is for showing data only (the same thing here, but only the table view), what I want when someone add data to the database using the `def Handel_Day_Operations_1 (self):`in the 2 nd gui that contain only the table view it will refresh automatically with the new row that has been added

Comment: One thing I don't understand. You're already using QSqlTableModel, why don't you insert the new data with that?

Comment: Well, I don't know how I use the simple method by another function `def Handel_Day_Operations_1 (self):`, and I use the table view only to show or update data, but when another one added something it will not automatically refresh I have to close the application and re open

Comment: As said, using QSqlTableModel *and* updating the database with the cursor isn't really effective, since QSqlTableModel already provides all required functions. I strongly suggest you to read the documentation about QSqlTableModel and all the inherited classes (QSqlQueryModel, QAbstractTableModel, QAbstractItemModel) and look for some tutorials on the topic. Look especially for [`insertRows()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#insertRows) and [`setData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#setData) or [`setRecord()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#setRecord).

Comment: thank you very much I try to read it, but I don't really understand how I can do it, that's why I have to ask here I' will keep looking for a solution, thanks again